# where to find server IP which I can setup in arango config files and make the db publicly available

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, arangodb, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to host arangodb in an ubuntu server, since arango GUI by default comes up at localhost:8529, I tried changing it to inet ip of the server but seems like it's a private ip and I cannot distribute it to the team to play around with DB, wanted to know how can I do this? I have already surfed google and stackoverflow but couldn't find the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make an ArangoDB database publicly available, always put a secured technology in front of it, and that internally connects back into ArangoDB as required.

I don't want to answer your question, because you shouldn't do it.

Comment: then how can I access the GUI? since it is anyways password protected, I don't think I'll be sharing the credentials to a third party, I'm trying to create some sort of POC, some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Install a proper web server (nginx, Apache), and configure it so that it redirects all the requests to `localhost:8529`